# Why are Al and Rocco depicted as Caporegimes at the Senate Hearing?

Tags: the-godfather-2

In *The Godfather: Part 2*, The Senate Hearing presents this chart of the Corleone Family:

[image: senate hearing]

From what I can see in the movie, Al Neri and Rocco Lampone are more Michael's personal bodyguards/handymen/hitmen than Capos. I think Capos run their own local business and don't do clipping jobs anymore are definitely not to be sent on a suicide mission like the one on Roth.

Are the Senate Hearing wrong in their jobs in the family?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While common, a caporegime isn't necessarily in charge of a sub-family or a crew, it can also refer to someone of high rank within a family, from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caporegime)...

> Caporegime is an Italian word, which is used to signify the head of a
>   family in Sicily, but has now come to mean a ranking member, similar
>   to captain or senior sergeant in a military unit.

And this is true of [Al Neri](http://www.imdb.com/character/ch0000810/bio)...

> In The Godfather Part II, **Neri** is seen to be an unofficial
>   second-in-command to Michael, and serves as one of Michael's capos
>   along with **Rocco Lampone** and Frank Pentangeli. He is responsible for a
>   prostitute's murder that guarantees the loyalty of Senator Pat Geary.
>   Neri was also personally responsible for the assassination of
>   Michael's brother Fredo Corleone, under Michael's orders for Fredo's
>   previous betrayal.

And [Rocco](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rocco_Lampone)...

> After Michael Corleone takes over the family, he makes [**Rocco**] Lampone a
>   caporegime. In the book, Michael puts together a secret regime for
>   Lampone, on the advice of Vito Corleone;

Even if this weren't true, it could also be possible the FBI considered them capos based on their imperfect knowledge of the Corleone family. The government only identified 4 ranks in the family: Boss-Underboss-Capos-Button Men. Neri and Rocco are clearly not button men, so while they might not run crews, they are clearly trusted by Michael and very high-ranking within the family.